# Does curly braces effect performance in C#?

Tags: c#

For single line if statement I have always preferred to use curly braces myself.
Like

```
if (condition)
{
   statement;
}
```

This statement can be written as

```
if(condition)
statement;
```

or

```
if(condition) statement;
```

I have searched through SO and other forum, most of the people prefer the first option. I know there's no effect in the run time performance.
Is there any performance factor for the first approach in compile time. How .NET framework or CLR handle decision statements like if or if-elseif ? Do the next options (second and the third) have any kind of enhanced performance ? May be the difference is negligible but I want to know how compiler handle this situation.

Comment: There is no difference....

Comment: The IL of all of those is identical. From a low level point of view there are **no** brackets, just conditional jumps.

Comment: If there is a difference in compilation times for those fragments its on the order of nanoseconds. So even if you choose the slower one, you'd have to write millions of lines of code to even see a small, 1 ms, difference. Focus on something more important like which one is more readable to you and your team.

Comment: ...and that's why we write the code in the most *readable* way (with indents, curly braces, empty lines, comments) - *compiler* wil generate the identical code. In case of interpretator, however, it takes time for the system to understand that there's nothing to do (with, say, extra curly braces); this used to be a problem in good old times when computers had 64k RAM and 1MHz CPU ;)

Comment: C# compiler follows the [C# grammar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664812(v=vs.71).aspx). According to the grammar, these two are the same grammar element, `if-statement`, which resolves as `if (boolean-expression) embedded-statement`. It's just that in the first case `embedded-statement` is `block` and in the second it's some other `*-statement`.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't.

C# compiled into CIL (Common Intermediate Language) which is the "assembly language" for the CLR (similar to "bytecode" in the Java world).

In CIL there is no concept of "braces". If-Else code blocks are expressed in CIL using "branch" commands, which are like conditional jumps. For example, "brc" followed by name of a label will jump to the label if the latest values on the stack are equal.

So, it doesn't matter if you put braces or not - it will be expressed the same way in the generated CIL code.

Comment: The question is about the time to compile, not run time performance.

Comment: He asked  " How .NET framework or CLR handle decision statements like if or if-elseif " - I answered regarding the CLR.

Answer (score 0):

no. after compiler finsihed his job. the code is the very same

Comment: What about the compile time ? I want to know that.

Comment: i don't know for sure but i suppose that his does not have any effect on anything but the known risk of adding lines to the statement when you are not using curly braces